# How to parse strings properly in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I have this function :

```
char *lookUpPageTable(char **array, int VPN)
   {
   if (array[VPN][0] == '1')
      {
      /*char **pageNumber = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)* 128);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++)
           {
           pageNumber[i] = array[VPN][i];
           }*/

      return array[VPN]; //this returns the whole number which I dont want
      }
   else
      {
      return "Page Fault";
      }
   }
```

The array I'm passing in as a parameter holds a list of numbers in the form 1 123456 where the first number is either a 1 or a 0 and the second number is a random number. This function checks the first number at index VPN in the array. If it is a zero, it should return a "Page Fault" string. If it is a 1, then the function should return the number after the 1.

For example, if i called lookUpPageTable(array, index)

The method should see if array[index][0] == '1'

If it does then return the remaining numbers at array[index]

else

return "page fault"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array[VPN]` is the `VPN`-th element of the `array`, which happens to be a pointer to the string `"1 123456"` as you say. If you return `array[VPN] + 1`, for example, it would be a pointer to the string `" 123456"`.

So you may return `array[VPN] + 2`, and you will obtain a pointer to the string `"123456"` as desired.

Note, however, that I am relying on your guarantee that the string's contents are indeed something of the form "1 123456", and I would recommend that your code should also verify that the string really is of that form.